# Display random image

Tags: java, android

I was wondering how to randomly select an image and set it to an image view. I know how to use the Rand method etc. But would there be a way to randomly show, quickly, other images and then go to the answer. Like you're rolling a dice.

Comment: Did you even try coding anything? Or do you expect somebody will provide you with a complete solution?

Comment: Orcourse I did, I just want a basic understanding of threading. I know it's somthing to do with processes.

Comment: There are many resources online on threading. As an Android developer you might want to check out AsyncTask.

Answer (score 1):

Use threading.& using random number generator get number which below your length of your array of images. and set that image in imageview

Comment: refer this- http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Answer (score 0):

You may use Timer and Random class:

Here is the code:

```
public class AndroidActivity extends Activity {

private ImageView frame;
private Image[] images = {blah, blah, blah};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);
    frame = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.frame);
    syncTask task = new syncTask(); 
    Timer timer= new Timer();
    task.schedule(timer, 0, 3000);;
}

private class syncTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        frame.setImageResource(images[random.nextInt(images.length)]);
    }       
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this gives you a bit idea.It may not be a perfect solution but you can try this out:)

```
final int[] imageViews = {
                R.id.imgview11, R.id.imgview12, R.id.imgview13, 
                R.id.imgview21, R.id.imgview22, R.id.imgview23, 
                R.id.imgview31, R.id.imgview32, R.id.imgview33  };

        final int[] images = {
                R.drawable.i1, R.drawable.i2, R.drawable.i3, 
                R.drawable.i4, R.drawable.i5, R.drawable.i6, 
                R.drawable.i7, R.drawable.i8, R.drawable.empty };

        final ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.newview);
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) { 

                Random rng = new Random(); 
                List<Integer> generated = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                {
                  while(true)
                  {
                     Integer next = rng.nextInt(9) ;
                     if (!generated.contains(next))
                     {
                        generated.add(next);
                        ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(imageViews[i]);
                        iv.setImageResource(images[next]);
                        break;
                     }
                   }
                }
                }
            });
```